# How to subclass Windows Explorer's window

Tags: windows, mfc, hook, subclass, dll-injection

I want to change color of listview of explorer.exe like this

[image]

I got the handle of listview window by GetTopWindow function and his family.

[image]

To subclass listview window of explorer.exe, I injected my dll code to explorer by following code.

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, g_hInstDll,
    dwExplorerListviewThreadId);
```

My dll is loaed by explorer.exe well.
And I subclassed the window procedure by **SetClassLongPtr**(for global subclass) in injected code.

**SetClassLongPtr** returns success but my subclass function(**SubclassProc**) receives only WM_CREATE WM_DESTROY and WM_MOVE messages. What's wrong? I expected to get **WM_NOTIFY and NM_CUSTOMDRAW**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this is not a ListView in the first place; it's instead using Microsoft's internal "DirectlUI" framework, which is used in several places in explorer. It doesn't use any of the Common Control messages such as NM_CUSTOMDRAW. There's pretty much no reasonable way to change the colors it uses.

(Also, generally it's best to use SetWindowLongPtr instead of SetClassLongPtr for subclassing a HWND: SetClassLong only changes the underlying template that is used for creating new windows, but may not end up changing any instances that were based on that. And you should not be using the same function - GetMsgProc - for both the hook callback and the subclass proc; they need to handle the message in different ways, the hook callback needs to call CallNextHookEx while the subclass proc needs to call CallWindowProc with the original wndproc. But none of this really matters since the control isn't a ListView in the first place...)

Comment: Hard to tell without full source code but it looks like GetMsgProc is the hook callback and SubclassProc is the callback for the subclassed window. IMO this is OK.

Comment: The question was edited after I posted my original answer - the original Qu had GetMsgProc for both.

Answer (score 0):

I think and suppose that the OS has special protections for the explorer.exe process, because otherwise it would be an easy target for malicious code or just applications that think they are more important than they actually are (if some people insist on putting back a shortcut on their desktop every time you start the application, imagine what they would do when they had this sort of access to explorer.exe - everything in the shell).

EDIT: I was intrigued by the question and did some more research, I think there is a more mundane reason, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/07/461912.aspx. (basically: explorer.exe is the window manager so doesn't know about message routing yet when it receives certain messages, which is why they can't be intercepted with message hooks).

Comment: There's nothing (well, very little) special about explorer: it's not actually the window manager as such: the 'window manager' referred to in the above article is USER32. Things have changed a bit since that 2005 article: the new DWM (Desktop Window Manager) process now handles some window managment and composition - but mostly on the graphic side of things; USER32 still manages input, hooks, and all things HWND-related.